# THREE.js Device Orientation Controls

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, three.js

So I plan to make a portfolio site, where you can see this planet I have made in THREE.js in wireframe, with a ring around it. I have made these, and applied some sort of animation; however while I may keep the animation, I would also like to implement Device Orientation Controls, so that using a mobile device you can orbit around the planet so to speak. I found that you can use:
    `controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera, true);` 
Which you can see I've added below but commented out as it causes the JavaScript to not render anything, just a white background. What am I doing wrong? this happens with all other types of controls such as orbit as well.
Heres the fiddle of what I've got so far
https://jsfiddle.net/0x4qftd9/

Comment: Your fiddle does not currently contain DeviceOrientationControls (commented out or otherwise). Please include them in the fiddle so it actually illustrates your problem.

Comment: As a starter, did you check for errors on the console? Did you include the DeviceOrientationControls script, as it is not included in the main three.js file?

Comment: @Paul-Jan I removed it to illustrate that it works without it, you can paste it in anywhere and it doesn't work

Comment: @Paul-Jan that would probably be a start, thanks for pointing out the issue for me 

Comment: THREE.DeviceOrientationControls is not a constructor; is the error I get once I've included the right files.